# How obtain usual output from package I created?

Tags: r, package, output

I have an issue with the output of the functions from the package I created!

When I run a function from my package the results are visualized in a new window.
[Output of my package that is impossible to copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxE8W.jpg)

For information, in my code I use function "View" as usual.

There is a specif option to visualize outputs in the script bartool?

The following is the output I would like to have:
[Usual R visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaNBH.jpg)

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Do you run the code from your package in RStudio as well? Could you provide some code that does that?

Comment: Yes, I run the code from RStudio. When I run the function I do not have any problem but if I run the fucntion calling the package containing the same function I have issues. To display the output of the function I use view(my dataframe), is this correct for packages? Or I have to use a different syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a package that contains only one function.

```
my_view <- function() {
  df <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=11:15)
  View(df)
}
```

After building it (`ctrl + shift + b` in RStudio) I've called the function and the dataframe is shown in new tab in RStudio.

What version of R and RStudio do you have? It is 3.6.3 and  1.2.5033 in my case. Could you try creating new package with only this function and check how the data is displayed?